# change names of files into different folders

Tags: rename

I actually have several folders with one file into each of them

for exemple :

```
name_folder1
        name_folder1_GCA_567.9_genomic.fna
name_folder2
        name_folder2_GCA_9002.0_genomic.fna
name_folder2
        name_folder2_GCA_234.0_genomic.fna
```

And what I'm trying to do is to get inside all these folder a different name and change the files' names such as:

```
name_folder1
        name_folder1.fna
name_folder2
        name_folder2.fna
name_folder2
        name_folder2.fna
```

Does someone have an idea?

I can also gather all my files into one file if it makes it easier:

```
name_folder1_GCA_567.9_genomic.fna
name_folder2_GCA_9002.0_genomic.fna
name_folder2_GCA_234.0_genomic.fna
```

change to :

```
name_folder1.fna
name_folder2.fna
name_folder2.fna
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: For the second choice I tried something like: `for f in /ncbi/*.fna; do mv -v "$f" "${f/_GCA.*_genomic/""}"; done`  my idea being to replace all the part from `_GCA` to `_genomic` by nothing for all files but it does not work I'm not really familiar with bash

Comment: I finally found ! by doing `for f in *.fna; do mv "$f" "${f/_GCA*_genomic/""}"; done`. :)